# Modal Popup Error

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax

I have a DataList that has a link button and I want this link button envoke a modal popup. I've copied the mpe code from another application where it works in a gridview. The error is thrown as soon as page is openned and each time the link button is clicked. The error is thrown in the ScriptResource file: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: elements". I understand something has null value but not sure what. Page has over a thousand lines so I'll just paste the part I'm working on.

```
<ItemTemplate>
                <tr  class="AssetMngnt-trHeaderRow_bgColor">
                    <td valign="top">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblIdent" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Printer_Ident") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>                            
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select" Text="Edit" />
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" nowrap>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" Text='<%# Eval("Network_Name") %>' runat="server" /> 
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbPrinterModel"
                            runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument="ShowAsset"
                            Text='<%# Eval("Printer_Mfg") + " " + (string)Eval("Printer_Model") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblLocation" Text='<%# Eval("Location") %>' runat="server" /> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"
                            runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument="IssueToners"
                            Text="Issue Toners" />

                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnShowPopup" style="display:none" />

                        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender runat="server" id="mpeIssueToners"
                                     TargetControlID="btnShowPopup"
                                     PopupControlID="pnlFvIssueTonersModal"
                                     CancelControlID="UpdateCancelButton"
                                     BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" >
                        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>


<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlFvIssueTonersModal" Visible="true" style="display:none">
 <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlFvIssueToners" Visible="true">

    <div id="AssetMngnt-FloatLeft_alt"">
        <!-- ISSUE TONERS FORM VIEW ******************************************************************************** -->   

        <asp:FormView ID="fvIssueCartridges" runat="server" DataSourceID="ODSIssueCartridges"                               
            OnItemUpdating="fvIssueCartridges_OnItemUpdating" OnItemUpdated="FormView1_Display_Update_Msg" 
            EnableViewState="False" 
            EmptyDataRowStyle-CssClass="AssetMngnt-panelRO" >
                <EditItemTemplate>

                </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>

        <!-- END ISSUE TONERS FORM VIEW **************************************************************************** -->
    </div>

 </asp:Panel>       
    <ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" BehaviorID="mdlPopup" runat="server" 
            TargetControlID="div" PopupControlID="div" CancelControlID="btnNo" 
            OnCancelScript="cancelClick();" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
    <div id="div" runat="server" align="center" class="confirm" style="display:none">
        <asp:Label Text="Form is empty - empty records are not allowed." 
            ForeColor="#000000" runat="server" ID="Label3" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnNo" runat="server" Text="Ok" Width="50px" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

The ModalPopupExtender1 takes care of things inside the FormView.

Thanks,
Risho